# Toggle .active class with vuejs 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This is my html code:

```
<nav class="nav nav-pills">
                            <li class="active text-center">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ FuImg::asset('img/mantee.svg') }}" alt="Camisetas Hombre">
                                <div>
                                    <span>hombre</span>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="text-center">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ FuImg::asset('img/womantee.svg') }}" alt="Camisetas Mujer">
                                <div>
                                    <span>mujer</span>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="text-center">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ FuImg::asset('img/babytee.svg') }}" alt="Body bebé">
                                <div>
                                    <span>bebé</span>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </nav>
```

I need the active class dynamic in my nav pills li items.

How can I do it with vuejs 2?

Comment: `:class`: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="text-center" :class={active: isActive} >
```

This basically says if `this.isActive === true` then the class "active" will be applied.

You have to set a property in your data object called isActive, and toggle it with javascript.  When it is true, it will apply your class, when it it is false, it wont.

Comment: How to toggle the class? Please, complete the solution

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample code below for reactive class

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="clicktorearrange"></button>
    <div :class="reactiveclass">when click the arrangement will change </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    reactiveclass: 'text-center pa-1 ma-1'
  }),
  methods: {
   clicktorearrange () {
      this.reactiveclass = 'text-right pa-2 ma-2'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```